# Склонение предложения из двух слов разного рода

Tags: склонение

*Прошу предоставить ежегодный оплачиваемый отпуск в связи с рождением ребенка Фоновой Анастасии Максимовны, родившейся...*

Или "родившегося" (речь идет о ребенке, но ребенок женского рода)?

Comment: Замените на «рождением дочери»; но лучше опустить «родившейся» — «с рождением родившейся» не годится — сразу указать дату.

Answer (score 0):

Если по грамматике, то конечно "родившейся". При таком построении фразы "ребенок" выглядит как приложение к основному грамматическому члену (ФИО).

А что до юридической сути, то тут каша какая-то. При рождении ребенка предоставляется отпуск по рождению и родам, а не ежегодный основной. Опять же есть разница, это отец прочит или мать. И много еще чего. В интернете полно образцов на все случаи жизни, Если вопрос из реальной жизни, то проще всего зайти в Кадры (или попросить кого-либо) уточнить ситуацию - и написать заявление под их шаблон.

Пусть даже это будет не совсем верно с точки зрения русского языка, важнее, что вас правильно поймут кадровики и юристы.